# ImportError: cannot import name SlotMap

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I am encountering an import error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bartis\Desktop\Python\TEC-KB\SlotMapper.pyw", line 9, in <module>
    from SlotMapper import SlotMap
  File "C:\Users\bartis\Desktop\Python\TEC-KB\SlotMapper.pyw", line 9, in <module>
    from SlotMapper import SlotMap
ImportError: cannot import name 'SlotMap
```

This should be a straightforward issue, but I can’t seem to find the problem. If I place the SlotMapper.py file in the same directory as the GUI I am using the import of SlotMap occurs without error. If I move the file to a directory under the current working directory and add - `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'appLib'))` I receive the error above. See import statements and modification of PYTHONPATH below. I know the PYTHONPATH has been modified after I checked it from the debugger. I also know since there are other files under appLib required for the GUI to operate. Finally, I have checked all of the imported files for a circular reference and find none… So stuck. Any suggestions welcome

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'appLib', 'KB-GUI'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'appLib'))

from tkinter import *

from SlotMapper import SlotMap
from ShelfTypeSelection import ShelfTypeSelector
from PackTypeSelection import PackTypeSlotMappingSelector
from EntryWidgets import EntryBase, ShelfSlotEntry
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because your file is named `SlotMapper.pyw`. The line

```
from SlotMapper import SlotMap
```

is trying to import `SlotMap` from your current file, hence the error. Try renaming your file to `slotmapper_test.pyw` or something like that, and everything should work as expected. You don't want your code files to have the same names as any modules you're trying to import, as the import mechanism will try to find the classes/functions there first, instead of searching your modules first.